# Android App crashes after for loop

Tags: java, android

I'm trying creating a timetable app in android, but it crashes when i press the button.
I allready tried to debugg it and I found out it always crashes when the switch case ends it doesnt matter in which order the case starts.
This is in the main class.
Thanks for your help!

```
public void setContentView(View view) {

      //getting information from "database"
        Subjects subjects1 = new Subjects(9, 10, "test1", "building1", "room1", "teacher1", 5);
        Subjects subjects2 = new Subjects(8, 11, "test2", "building2", "room2", "teacher1", 1);

        //creating list and add items
        List<Subjects> listTimetable = new ArrayList<>();
        listTimetable.add(subjects1);
        listTimetable.add(subjects2);

        //new TextView with atribs
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(25);
        textView.setPadding(0, 0, 60, 0);


        //get objects for timetable and sett strings

        for (int i=0; i < listTimetable.size(); i++) {

            Subjects newOne = listTimetable.get(i);
            int stringNewOne = newOne.getWeekday();

            switch (stringNewOne) {
                case (1):
                    //setTextView a text
                    textView.setText("Start Time" + newOne.getTimeStart()+"End Time"+newOne.getTimeEnd()+"\n" + " " +
                            newOne.getRoom
                                    () + " " + newOne
                            .getBuilding());
                    TableRow tableRowMon = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.trMonday);
                    tableRowMon.addView(textView);

                    break;
                case (2):
                    textView.setText("Start Time" + newOne.getTimeStart()+"End Time"+newOne.getTimeEnd()+"\n" + " " +
                            newOne.getRoom
                                    () + " " + newOne
                            .getBuilding());
                    TableRow tableRowTue = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.trTuesday);
                    tableRowTue.addView(textView);
                    break;
                case (3):
                    textView.setText("Start Time" + newOne.getTimeStart()+"End Time"+newOne.getTimeEnd()+"\n" + " " +
                            newOne.getRoom
                                    () + " " + newOne
                            .getBuilding());
                    TableRow tableRowWed = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.trWednesday);
                    tableRowWed.addView(textView);
                    break;
                case (4):
                    textView.setText("Start Time" + newOne.getTimeStart()+"End Time"+newOne.getTimeEnd()+"\n" + " " +
                            newOne.getRoom
                                    () + " " + newOne
                            .getBuilding());
                    TableRow tableRowThur = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.trThrisday);
                    tableRowThur.addView(textView);
                    break;
                case (5):
                    textView.setText("Start Time" + newOne.getTimeStart()+"End Time"+newOne.getTimeEnd()+"\n" + " " +
                            newOne.getRoom
                                    () + " " + newOne
                            .getBuilding());
                    TableRow tableRowFri = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.trFriday);
                    tableRowFri.addView(textView);
                    break;
                case (6):
                    textView.setText("Start Time" + newOne.getTimeStart() + "End Time" + newOne.getTimeEnd() + "\n" + " " +
                            newOne.getRoom
                                    () + " " + newOne
                            .getBuilding());
                    TableRow tableRowSat = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.trSaturday);
                    tableRowSat.addView(textView);

                    break;
                case (7):
                    textView.setText("Start Time" + newOne.getTimeStart()+"End Time"+newOne.getTimeEnd()+"\n" + " " +
                            newOne.getRoom
                                    () + " " + newOne
                            .getBuilding());
                    TableRow tableRowSun = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.trSunday);
                    tableRowSun.addView(textView);
                    break;

                    default: break;
            }


        }







        //add tablerow view Textview





        //Console debugging Logging
        Log.d("Test", "message");
        String log = Integer.toString(subjects1.getTimeStart());
        Log.d("school", log);


    }
```

Comment: can you post the logcat??? and try printing subject1 object too...

Comment: We'll need a [mcve] to help you

Comment: Xoce웃Пepeúpa
Blackbelt allready gave the right answer, but a quick question why should i print the subject one?
I'm asking because so i can maybe help myself next time :)
@cricket_007
Its the Minimal code i can give, without this it woudn't work, or is there a better method to do it, just wanted to know to do it better next time

Comment: I don't think 7 switch cases is minimal

Comment: @cricket_007

How could i solve this in an better way, as you can see I'm really new here and also a new programmer, just want to learn :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but if the answer below fixes your issue, then I won't waste your time with code fixes. There is a CodeReview Stackexchange for that

Comment: @cricket_007
I'm trying to learn thats and thanks for the tip with CodeReview.
Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move

```
   //new TextView with atribs
   TextView textView = new TextView(this);
   textView.setTextSize(25);
   textView.setPadding(0, 0, 60, 0);
```

inside the for loop. A `View` can't have multiple parents and the same `View` can't be added multiple times